# How to get the current working directory's absolute path in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I get the current working directory's absolute path on the iPhone using Objective-C?

Comment: The question says OS X but the tag says iPhone. Which one is right?

Comment: Actually i needed for both. i'm developing an iPhone application in XCode on MAC OS X

Comment: That means you need it for the iPhone API, right?

Comment: what absolute path on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't get the absolute path on device, at least with official SDK. Please make me correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this works on iPhone, but it should.

```
char *buf = getwd();
NSString *cwd = [NSString stringWithCString:buf encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
free(buf);
```

You might need to fiddle with the right encoding...

**EDIT:** aaaehm, you might also just want to try NSFileManager's `currentDirectoryPath` method...